# Tailwind not getting imported in Laravel

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css

I have a Laravel project and I'm trying to install Tailwind.

I have a `tailwind.css` file: \resources\assets\stylesheets\tailwind.css

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

Which I import in:\resources\assets\stylesheets\index.css

```
@import "tailwind.css"
```

My webpack.mix.js file:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .options({
      processCssUrls: false,
      postCss: [ tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js') ],
    });
```

And tailwind.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

When I run the app and check the generated `http://localhost/dist/css/app.css` I see this:

```
/* Import Tailwind*/


@tailwind base;


@tailwind components;


@tailwind utilities
```

I've installed tailwind through npm, can also find the tailwind folder in my node_modules folder.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included `index.css` in your `app.scss` file?

You really don't need to put Tailwind through a `sass` parser if all you're doing is including the base styles etc. anyway.

Assuming you have Tailwind installed as a dependency already, you can include Tailwind in your project as follows:

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/assets/stylesheets/index.css', 'public/css', [
        require('tailwindcss'),
    ]);
```